# ionic2 native datepicker bug

Tags: angular, ionic2

first, i wouldn't like to use `ion-datetime`, because it's not friendly...

.html:  (if type is 'date', it's not work...and if there is no read-only attribute, it is also a bug in real-machine, but i don't care, i just set read-only.)

```
<ion-input name="date" type="text" tappable
    (click)="openDatePicker()" readonly
    [(ngModel)]="date[column.tid]"></ion-input>
```

.ts:

```
openDatePicker() {
    DatePicker.show({
      date: new Date(),
      mode: 'date',
      locale: 'zh-CN',
    }).then(
      date => console.log('Got date: ', date),
      err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
    );
}
```

now, i have to touch twice before it will work.
so, how do I fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by: "I have to touch twice before it will work"?

Comment: must click INPUT twice, the first time it does not work

Comment: in my case I use `disabled=true` instead of `readonly` to avoid the keyboard to show up. Maybe try that. I tested on Samsung Galaxy S4, it works fine, it just needs one click and the native datepicker shows up.

Comment: thx, but it's not work on iPhone7P

Comment: Ok, what about if you have something like: `<div (click)="openDatePicker()" ></div>` does it still need double click to trigger `openDataPicker()`? If not, maybe you could trick it by hiding the `<ion-input>` on your DOM and edit it when `openDataPicker()` return the result (so form submit would act with correct input) and edit display of the `<div>` for the user reading convenience.